# How to accelerate list of saxpy's in CUDA

Tags: cuda, numba, cublas

I have a single matrix and a list of triplets of length BATCH_SIZE:

```
float matrix[3000][3000]

(float vector[3000], uint32_t index, float alpha)
```

For each triplet, I perform a saxpy with:

```
matrix[index] += vector * alpha.
```

I do this for many batches.

I was wondering what the best way to accelerate the code in CUDA was. I'm open to using Python libraries too.

Comment: Because there are no batched `saxpy` implementations I am aware, I suppose the answer is to write some code....

Comment: perform a reduction across your triplets, reducing each set of duplicated indices to a single instance.  Then perform a single saxpy, treating your matrix as a long vector.  If you don't take some approach like that, you will be stuck doing operations of length 3000 serially, and an operation of length 3000 is unlikely to saturate your GPU.  If you are unfamiliar with CUDA and working in python, you might investigate `cupy`.

Comment: How would you reduce the triplets while making sure to saturate the GPU?

Comment: sort the triplets by index, to group like indices together.  This would be an operation of length `BATCH_SIZE` which you haven't indicated.  Then perform a reduce-by-key operation, which would be an operation of `3000*BATCH_SIZE`.  Then perform your saxpy operation, which would be an operation of `3000*reduced_size`.

Comment: I’m asking how do you do the reduce by key for one key

Comment: the reduce-by-key would take redundant indices, and scaled-add their vectors together, so they are represented by a single instance/vector.  Probably you don't understand what reduce-by-key is in this context (e.g. a thrust reduce_by_key).  You may wish to start by understanding how  a thrust reduce_by_key operation works.  The whole point of this description is to be able to handle redundant indices in parallel, so as to get out of the serialized issuance of work.

Comment: OK. Will do. Is there no parallel multiple cublas saxpy operation that can do this?

Comment: not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible method using [thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).  It follows roughly the sequence outlined in the comments.  The basic idea is to flatten everything, and reduce elements that add to the same vector element together:

1. multiply each `vector` element by its corresponding `alpha`.
2. create indexing to allow sorting of the `vector` elements to bring like-index elements together
3. sort_by_key, to bring like-index elements together
4. reduce_by_key, to combine like-index elements together
5. add the reduced values to the appropriate elements in `matrix`

The following example shows the above method, and compares it from a timing perspective to the loop-saxpy method.  On my Tesla V100, CUDA 10.1, the "parallel" method is about 3x faster than the loop-saxpy method, for `BATCH_SIZE` of 1000, and `index` constrained to a relatively small footprint:

```
$ cat t1714.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}


typedef float dt;
const int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;
const int ds = 3000;
const int RANGE = 10;

struct my_gen
{
  int range;
  my_gen(int r) : range(r) {};
  __host__
  int operator ()(){
    return rand()%range;
    }
};

//struct my_seq


using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

// data setup

  thrust::device_vector<dt> matrix(ds*ds);
  thrust::device_vector<dt> result1 = matrix;
  thrust::device_vector<dt> vector(ds*BATCH_SIZE);
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_index(BATCH_SIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<dt>  alpha(BATCH_SIZE);

  thrust::generate(h_index.begin(), h_index.end(), my_gen(RANGE));
  thrust::fill(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 1.0);
  thrust::fill(alpha.begin(), alpha.end(), 1.0);

// first, time serial op

  thrust::host_vector<dt> h_alpha = alpha;

  unsigned long long my_dt = dtime_usec(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < BATCH_SIZE; i++)
    thrust::transform(vector.begin()+(i*ds), vector.begin()+((i+1)*ds), result1.begin()+(h_index[i]*ds), result1.begin()+(h_index[i]*ds), _1*h_alpha[i]+_2);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  my_dt = dtime_usec(my_dt);
  std::cout << "serial time: " << my_dt/(float)USECPSEC << " seconds" << std::endl;


// now time parallel op
  thrust::device_vector<int> vi(ds*BATCH_SIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> index = h_index;
  thrust::device_vector<int> keys(ds*BATCH_SIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<dt> vr(ds*BATCH_SIZE);
  auto my_ti = thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1%ds);
  my_dt = dtime_usec(0);
  thrust::transform(vector.begin(), vector.end(), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(alpha.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1/ds)), vector.begin(), _1*_2); // multiply by alpha
  thrust::transform(my_ti, my_ti+(ds*BATCH_SIZE), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(index.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1/ds)), _1*ds), vi.begin(), _1 + _2);
  thrust::sort_by_key(vi.begin(), vi.end(), vector.begin()); // collect like indices
  int key_size = (thrust::reduce_by_key(vi.begin(), vi.end(), vector.begin(), keys.begin(), vr.begin())).first - keys.begin(); // add like indices together
  auto my_pi = thrust::make_permutation_iterator(matrix.begin(), keys.begin());
  thrust::transform(vr.begin(), vr.begin()+key_size, my_pi, my_pi, _1 + _2); // perform final add
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  my_dt = dtime_usec(my_dt);
  std::cout << "parallel time: " << my_dt/(float)USECPSEC << " seconds" << std::endl;
  thrust::host_vector<dt> h_matrix = matrix;
  thrust::host_vector<dt> h_result1 = result1;
  for (int i = 0; i < ds*ds; i++) if (h_matrix[i] != h_result1[i]) {std::cout << " mismatch at " << i << " was: " << h_matrix[i] << " should be: " << h_result1[i] << std::endl; return 0;}
}
$ nvcc -o t1714 t1714.cu -std=c++11
$ ./t1714
serial time: 0.018015 seconds
parallel time: 0.005337 seconds
$
```

I don't claim correctness for this code or any other code that I post. Anyone using any code I post does so at their own risk. I merely claim that I have attempted to address the questions in the original posting, and provide some explanation thereof. I am not claiming my code is defect-free, or that it is suitable for any particular purpose. Use it (or not) at your own risk.